How fast do solutions of elliptic PDEs vanish at the boundary?
For some integer $d \ge 2$, let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be a bounded open set with continuous boundary : by that I mean that around each point $x\in\partial\Omega$, there exists a neighborhood of $x$ around which $\partial\Omega$ is equal to the graph of a continuous function (I do not want to assume more regularity than this if possible).
Now consider the boundary value problem :
$$\begin{cases}
\tag1
Lu(x) &= -1\ \ \text{ for } x\in\Omega\\
u(x) &= 0\ \ \text{ for } x\in\partial\Omega
\end{cases} $$
where $L$ is a differential operator of the form :
$$Lf(x) = b(x)\cdot\nabla f(x) + \frac12\sum_{1\le i,j\le d} \Sigma_{ij}(x)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}  f(x),$$
where the coefficients $b:\Omega\to\mathbb R^d$, $\Sigma :\Omega\to\mathbb R^{d\times d} $ are assumed to be smooth, uniformly bounded, and satisfy
$$\xi^T\Sigma(x)\xi \ge \sigma_0\|\xi\|^2 \ \ \text{ for all } \xi\in\mathbb R^d$$
for some $\sigma_0>0$ and all $x\in\Omega$. I believe those conditions are enough to ensure the existence of a unique classical solution of $(1)$ which I will call $u^*$ (but please do let me know if that's not the case).
My question is the following : does it hold that $u^*(x)\to 0$ whenever $d(x,\partial\Omega)\to 0$ ? And can we get estimates of the form
$$u^*(x) \sim d(x,\partial\Omega)^\alpha $$ whenever convergence holds ? ($d(x,\partial\Omega)$ denotes the Euclidean distance ox $x$ to the boundary of $\Omega$)
If this problem is too hard, positive results in the case when $\partial\Omega$ is assumed to be smooth will also be helpful.

Motivation : The equation $(1)$ describes the Mean First Passage Time (MFPT) of a stochastic process with generator $L$ to the boundary $\Omega$ (see these and these lecture notes by Miranda Holmes-Cerfon for more on the relationship between this PDE and stochastic processes).
I want to get some error bounds on an algorithm which computes the MFPT, but it's hard to control what happens close to $\partial\Omega$ due to the lack of regularity, hence I would like to "split" $\Omega$ into a compact set $\widetilde\Omega\Subset\Omega $ with smooth boundary where the error is easier to control, and the "remainder" $\Omega\setminus \widetilde\Omega$ where I hope to control the error by an estimate of the form I ask in my question.
Thank you very much for your time !

You do not get a classical solution. In fact, consider $\Omega = U_1(0) \setminus \{0\}$ (open unit ball without the origin). Then, the PDE $-\Delta u = 1$ with Dirichlet BC does not have a classical solution. Note that the weak solution "ignores" the Dirichlet BC at the origin since a single point is too small.
The keyword concerning continuity up to the boundary is "Wiener criterion".
Edit: It is also possible to have similar counterexamples with slightly more regular boundary. In dimensions $d \ge 3$, you can remove a Lebesgue spine from a nice set.
In dimension $d = 2$, I believe one can take
$$
\Omega = U_1(0) \setminus \bigg( \{0\} \cup \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty \operatorname{cl} U_{r_n}(x_n)\bigg)$$
for some sequence $x_n \to 0$ and for $r_n \searrow 0$ fast enough. The solution will be discontinuous at $\{0\}$. But still, around $0$, the boundary is not a graph.
In two dimensions, your boundary regularity could be enough to get continuity.

thank you for your answer, I will look into that "Wiener criterion" that you mentioned. Regarding your counterexample, it doesn't work as I still require the boundary to be continuous (but not more than that), and your $\Omega$ does not have a continuous boundary (it's not connected). I admit I didn't word it very well, so I have edited to hopefully clear the ambiguity, sorry.

In case $d \ge 3$ the answer is still negative. I think you could continuity from your boundary regularity in case $d = 2$. See the edit.
